# Google Drive Api Get Issue

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, quota

Its really frustrating to not know what is causing the issue, I am trying to get Total Quota and Total Free Space left in the user Google Drive ,
Below is the summary of my code, the code is crashing at line "com.google.api.services.drive.model.About about = mGooSvc.about().get().execute();" Error stack is at the bottom

```html
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;

//within Class variables declared
private static com.google.api.services.drive.Drive mGooSvc;
    private static com.google.api.services.drive.Drive m_client;
    private final HttpTransport m_transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
    private final JsonFactory m_jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private GoogleAccountCredential m_credential;
    private static Drive service;

//with in protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   //GoogleDrive
        m_credential=GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE));
        //Drive
                m_client = new com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Builder(
                m_transport, m_jsonFactory, m_credential).setApplicationName("com.dbprox.css")
                .build();
        mGooSvc = new com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Builder(
                m_transport,m_jsonFactory,m_credential.usingOAuth2(
               getApplicationContext(),
                Collections.singletonList(com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))).build();



//on button click Listener
 startActivityForResult(m_credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);

//onActivityResult

if ((requestCode == REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER || requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION)) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
                    String accountName = data.getExtras().getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                    if (accountName != null) {
                       m_credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                    Toast.makeText(this,m_credential.getSelectedAccountName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                // call method to start accessing Google Drive

                try {

                   // com.google.api.services.drive.model.About about = mGooSvc.about().get().execute();
                 com.google.api.services.drive.model.About about = mGooSvc.about().get().execute();//  service.about().get().execute(); //service.about().get().execute();

                    Log.i("Google Drive",about.getStorageQuota().getLimit().toString());
//                    System.out.println("Current user name: " + about.getStorageQuota().getLimit().toString());

                    // TOTAL - USED = FREE SPACE
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
                }
            }

        }else {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);}
```

Below is the Stack Trace

02-07 13:16:34.414 27038-27038/com.dbprox.css E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null
02-07 13:16:34.414 27038-27038/com.dbprox.css E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.accounts.Account.(Account.java:48)
02-07 13:16:34.414 27038-27038/com.dbprox.css E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
02-07 13:16:34.414 27038-27038/com.dbprox.css E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:255)
02-07 13:16:34.414 27038-27038/com.dbprox.css E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:279)
02-07 13:16:34.414 27038-27038/com.dbprox.css E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
02-07 13:16:34.414 27038-27038/com.dbprox.css E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
02-07 13:16:34.414 27038-27038/com.dbprox.css E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
02-07 13:16:34.414 27038-27038/com.dbprox.css E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
02-07 13:16:34.414 27038-27038/com.dbprox.css E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.dbprox.css.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:244)
02-07 13:16:34.414 27038-27038/com.dbprox.css E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5552)
02-07 13:16:34.414 27038-27038/com.dbprox.css E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3591)
02-07 13:16:34.414 27038-27038/com.dbprox.css E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3638) 
02-07 13:16:34.414 27038-27038/com.dbprox.css E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:154) 
02-07 13:16:34.414 27038-27038/com.dbprox.css E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
02-07 13:16:34.414 27038-27038/com.dbprox.css E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
02-07 13:16:34.414 27038-27038/com.dbprox.css E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
02-07 13:16:34.414 27038-27038/com.dbprox.css E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5347) 
02-07 13:16:34.414 27038-27038/com.dbprox.css E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
02-07 13:16:34.414 27038-27038/com.dbprox.css E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
02-07 13:16:34.414 27038-27038/com.dbprox.css E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:835) 
02-07 13:16:34.414 27038-27038/com.dbprox.css E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:651) 
02-07 13:16:34.414 27038-27038/com.dbprox.css E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: have you checked out the [Drive.Builder v2](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/Drive.Builder.html#setApplicationName(java.lang.String)) docs? The JSONFactory should be of `com.google.api.client.extensions.android.json.AndroidJsonFactory`. Try to replace the current GSONFactory set into the proper one.

Comment: @adjuremods Same error after the import replaced v                          Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source) at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:255) at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:279)

Comment: i tried to debug and it says it fails with Error Message :unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception.

Comment: Were you able to go through with the Drive [Getting Quickstart](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart) or [Project creation guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started)? From what I can see it has something to do with authentication and thay may be the reason why you're getting the `IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null` error. Once you've properly authorized your app, you should be able to properly use the Drive API by then. Hope this helps!

Comment: @adjuremods,yes i followed the Getting Qickstart abd Project Creation guide, the  m_credential and drive builder are successful and it shows me login name and Authentication token , it only fails at com.google.api.services.drive.model.About about = mGooSvc.about().get().execute();

Comment: Well, when I checked the [v2 About: get sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get#examples), its technically the same with yours. I'm not sure what the issue is now currently. My guess is is it may be due to the Google API version used might be the latest one and not specific for v2. I'd recommend to migrate your project to the latest version, though.

Comment: @adjuremods what do i need to pass to   private static void printAbout(Drive service) or how to call this methord